# Java: Getting a substring before a certain character

Tags: java, string

For example:

`patient1234567 GMT+ howtoget`

I want to get the information preceding the `+` and in this case that would be `GMT`. The strings I'm working with have over 1000 characters and I've tried indexof and could not get it to work.

Can anyone please offer any assistance?

Comment: Did you try string split etc? Did you read String API doc?

Comment: `String#indexOf`, `String#substring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String[] data = "patient1234567 GMT+ howtoget".split("\\+")[0].split(" ");
System.out.println(data[data.length - 1]);
```

Output :

```
GMT
```